# How to prevent $wpdb->prepare stripping a leading zero in variable value?

Tags: wpdb

I have a simple `database_read` function and per accident I noticed order_id's starting with a leading zero would not give me the expected results.

It turns out using `$wpdb->prepare` strips out leading zero's. How can i prevent this and still use the `prepare` method?

Here's the function:

```
function database_read($order_id)
{
    // $order_id = intval($order_id);//this will also strip leading zero
    // echo $order_id;
    //  exit();

    global $wpdb;

    // This doesn't work: 
    // $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT payStatus FROM test_table WHERE ref = %s",$order_id);

    // This works:
    $sql = "SELECT payStatus FROM test_table WHERE ref = {$order_id}";

    $res = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);                     
    return $res;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$order_id = 012345;
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT payStatus FROM test_table WHERE ref = %s",$order_id);//<-- this doesn't work
var_dump($sql);
echo '<br/>';

$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT payStatus FROM test_table WHERE ref = %d",$order_id);//<-- this doesn't work
var_dump($sql);
echo '<br/>';        

$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT payStatus FROM test_table WHERE ref = %f",$order_id);//<-- this doesn't work
var_dump($sql);
echo '<br/>'; 

$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT payStatus FROM test_table WHERE ref = %s",(string)$order_id);//<-- this doesn't work
var_dump($sql);
echo '<br/>';

$order_id = '012345';
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT payStatus FROM test_table WHERE ref = %s",$order_id);//<-- this doesn't work
var_dump($sql);
echo '<br/>';
```

You will notice that all but the last convert to `5349`. [This is because a leading zero in PHP indicates an octal number.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) Your zero isn't being stripped, exactly. It is being converted into a decimal.

In effect, you are passing in an octal number or you have somewhere converted a string with a leading zero into an integer. I can't tell exactly where that happens but you need to prevent it.

Really, it isn't `prepare` that is doing this. It is more PHP core.

Comment: Wow, didn't see that one. In my case the leading zero is part of a random barcode (...should have excluded a leading zero :(). Each barcode is stored in mysql varchar field. I am going to look into my php code and check where i have converted it to a decimal